# WinHttpRequest stopped working when code used in different file

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works perfectly in one file, but when I tried using it in another, I am getting error "user-defined type not defined" and "http As New WinHttpRequest" is highlighted. What might be the  reason this suddenly does not work?

Thank you!

```
url = Links(2, j)
Dim http As New WinHttpRequest
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.send
Dim Resp As String: Resp = http.ResponseText
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `WinHttpRequest` library is not added to the project and in the other Excel file it was.

Add the `WinHTTP` library from the VBE menu > Tools > References:

[image]

The above method is called **Early binding**. The one below is called **Late binding**:

If you want to avoid adding the library and work with a tiny slower code and without Intellisense, use this:

```
Dim http As Object
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

Then simply copying and pasting this one will always work:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")    
    http.Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", False
    http.Send
    Debug.Print http.ResponseText

End Sub
```